# How to the Clicked image ID in Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I loop and display the images from the database. Every image has a unique ID and I want to get the ID when an image is clicked.

```html
<div v-for="kudo in catkudo"  style="width:20%;float:left;display:block;height:80px;">
  <div class="kudos_img" style="">
     <img style="width:40%" v-bind:value="kudo.id" v-on:click="select($event)" v-model="kudocat" :src="'/kudosuploads/badges/'+kudo.image" alt="">
     <p>{{ kudo.catname }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  addKudoPost: function(profile_id){


      var formkudodata = new FormData();

    formkudodata.append('kudodescription', this.kudodescription);

    formkudodata.append('kudouser', this.selected);

    formkudodata.append('kudoimage', this.kudocat);



    axios.post('/addNewsFeedKudoPost', formkudodata)
    .then(response=>{

        if(response.status===200){
           this.posts = response.data.posts; 
           this.birthdays = response.data.birthdays; 
           console.log(this.kudodescription);
           console.log(this.selected);
           $('#post-box')[0].innerHTML = "";
           this.newsfeedPostImages();

       }

   })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

I need to get the ID and assign it to a variable when the image is clicked.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the input you get in catkudo ?

Answer (score 0):

`v-on:click="select($event, kudo.id)"`

If your kudo indeed has an id, then this will work. And you need to modify select to take in said id.

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` method has to have `kudo.id` as parameter.

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="kudo in catkudo"  style="width:20%;float:left;display:block;height:80px;">
    <div class="kudos_img" style="">
       <img style="width:40%" :value="kudo.id" @click="select(kudo.id)" v-model="kudocat" :src="'/kudosuploads/badges/'+kudo.image" alt="">
       <p>{{ kudo.catname }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    select (id) {
      console.log(id, 'is selected');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working I update with my code .. could you check

Comment: @Salvator Please do not edit other users' answers to extend your question. If your new code is relevant to this question, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56689731/edit). If this code would alter the question significantly (to a place where both answers here would be invalidated), [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I recommend you to take the [tour], to get more accustomed to the site. See also [ask] and [answer] to learn what is a proper question and a proper answer and how are they different.